# CSS - Fix position of a submenu when scrolling the container div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a submenu opening when I click on a button. When I scroll in the container div, the submenu stays in the middle of the page. I would like it to stay under the button

```css
div.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.filter_container {
  padding: 40px;
}

.index_filters_selected__NkclA {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eceff4;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.modal_sub_menu {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d6d9e5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 55;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="filter_container">
    <div class="index_filters_selected__NkclA ">
      <span>Subject</span>
      <svg width="12" height="13" viewBox="0 0 12 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">
            <path d="M2.25 5L6 8.75L9.75 5" stroke="#3D4252" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
         </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_sub_menu">
      <form>
        <div class="filters_forms_filters_form__SbQTV">
          <label for="email_subject">
                  <div class="label">Subject </div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="email_subject" class="" value="">
               </label>
          <div><button type="button" class="cancel_button">Cancel</button><button type="submit">Apply</button></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</span>pidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mplante/1xpszjb2/53/

Thanks!

Comment: Consider adding the code for "submenu opening when I click on a button" to make a functional example

Comment: NOTE: I made a snippet of your code and formatted it a bit to highlight the fact that your HTML is malformed as posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `position: relative` to `.filter_container` to make it the position reference for the absolutely positioned submenu.

```css
div.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.filter_container {
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative
}

.index_filters_selected__NkclA {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eceff4;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.modal_sub_menu {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d6d9e5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 55;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="filter_container">
    <div class="index_filters_selected__NkclA ">
      <span>Subject</span>
      <svg width="12" height="13" viewBox="0 0 12 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">
            <path d="M2.25 5L6 8.75L9.75 5" stroke="#3D4252" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
         </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_sub_menu">
      <form>
        <div class="filters_forms_filters_form__SbQTV">
          <label for="email_subject">
                  <div class="label">Subject </div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="email_subject" class="" value="">
               </label>
          <div><button type="button" class="cancel_button">Cancel</button><button type="submit">Apply</button></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</span>pidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it created another problem: the submenu does not go beyond the container. Let's say my container div width is not 400px anymore but 200px, the submenu is stuck in the container : https://jsfiddle.net/mplante/1xpszjb2/61/

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, but if you want to make the `input` field smaller, you can use the `size` attribute in the `input` tag, like `<input type="text" size="10">` or similar (adjust value as needed and also add all other attributes you already have). This does *not*  limit the possible input value, BTW.